# Find diameter of an object in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am having an issue in finding diameter of an object in image using MATLAB. Below is the source code for it. Kindly help me what is missing in my code.

```
obj=imread('C:\Users\Khan\Desktop\basebal.jpg');
imshow(obj);
red =obj(:,:,1);
green =obj(:,:,2);
blue =obj(:,:,3);
figure
subplot(2,3,1),imshow(obj);title('original image');
subplot(2,3,2),imshow(red);title('red ball');
subplot(2,3,3),imshow(green);title('green ball');
subplot(2,3,4),imshow(blue);title('blue ball');

figure
level =0.41;
bw2=im2bw(blue,level);
subplot(2,2,1),imshow(bw2);title('blue plane thresholded');
fill =imfill(bw2,'holes');
subplot(2,2,2),imshow(fill);title('holes filled');
clear = imclearborder(fill);
subplot(2,2,3),imshow(clear);title('remove blobs on border');
se=strel('disk',7);
open=imopen(fill,se);
subplot(2,2,4),imshow(open);title('remove small blobs');
diameter = regionprops(open,'MajorAxisLength');
figure
imshow(obj)
d=imdistline;
```

The code is for showing the diameter of a blob and show it on line but 
there is something missing due to which results are not accurate.

This figure shows the input and output of the code:

[image: output]

This is the input image:

[image: basebal.jpg]

Comment: Please include your input image, describe what you intended to achieve, and how the actual output is wrong. "something missing" is difficult to interpret. Thanks!

Comment: The Image is not uploading I guess I am a new member

Comment: Obviously, the "blue plane thresholded" image is not a good start. Could you please also upload the original color image? You might want to look into thresholding based on color, not just on intensity in the blue channel.

Comment: yup let me upload the original image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how accurate and automated you want the result you have a couple of opportunities.

The easiest is to use `d = imdistline;`, which is an interactive tool, which allows you to measure the ball like a ruler.

```
imshow(obj)
d = imdistline;
```

Alternatively you can use the `imfindcircles` function, which allows you to specify a range of radii and then find circular objects with such radii. Though, you have to play with the sensitivity, I fairly easily found that the following works

```
[centers,radii] = imfindcircles(obj,[100 150],'Sensitivity',0.95);
```

Which gives me that the radius is `109.6432` and thus the diameter is `219.2864`.

You can additionally plot the circle with

```
imshow(obj)
viscircles(centers,radii);
```

which gives

[image: baseball]